# AJAX loading and Drag'n Drop file

Tags: jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I write here my question because i don't found any solution to it :(

I make this code to make an UPLOAD DIV on my page :

[JS Fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/MkkHJ/1/)
Code :

```
$(document).on('dragover dragleave dragenter', '#drop-files', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$(document).on('drop', '#drop-files', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer) {
        if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length <= 3) {
                var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                                                  $.each(files, function(index, file) {
                        if (!!window.FileReader) {
....
```

It works fine on FIDDLE with CHROME, FIREFOX and IE10.
Because all is loaded at same time.

But if the **"drop-files"** DIV is loaded in AJAX to the page, after the body and with his JS file, it don't work on Firefox and IE, only works fine on Chrome.
I don't understand why? because i use **$(document)on('drop'** ... to make it working fine :(

On CHROME it ALERT me with the number of files ...
On FIREFOX and IE10 it open the file on the browser :(

Is some one have a solution please ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the code i post in the first post works fine.

Just adding for Firefox this line before :

```
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
```

The 'drop' event works fine on the DOM after we append the DIV ...

If you make Ajax like me you must use `$(document).on('drop', ....`
If you append the DIV before the script, you can use normal `$('#DIV').drop(....`

Good link with event list and compatibility :
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t18

Answer (score 0):

Finally the only solution who works fine was to load the "document.on(drop" at the page loading. It is not important if the DIV is already there or not ... but the script must be loaded first. When you will APPEND the DIV the DRAG N DROP will works fine with it.

But i repeat, it works fine on CHROME !
This trick is only for FireFox and IE10 !
IE9 don't understand file Drag'n Drop ...

I wish one day this problem will be solved by the Explorers ...
Like the PASSWORD SAVE on AJAX LOGIN FORM who will finally be fixed with the next FF and CHROME versions ... it already works on IE :p